# v-select multiple display text if empty selection

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

I have this `<v-select multiple persistent-placeholder></v-select>` component and I would like to display some custom content if selection is empty, like `No entry selected yet`.

Is there any chance I can achieve this? I looked at props and slots but none seem to fit my need. I tried the `no-data` named slot but did not work.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "custom content" do you want to show? If it's just a plain or dynamic string, you can use `placeholder` prop. If you want to show some HTML, this won't help

Comment: Custom text could do the job, but indeed this would be nicer if it were custom html content. I considered having a dynamic placeholder but I'd like the placeholder to be visible anyway (which is why I added `persistent-placeholder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best approach with the current vuetify version is to use the placeholder as you mention in the comments. Check this codepen I made: https://codepen.io/cmfc31/pen/GROyQMa

I just added some css to make it look like an item

```css
.no-entries input::placeholder {
    color: #212121 !important;
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks! This is nice! I thought the "No entry selected" had to replace the "Standard" label which would make the input unclear but this is because I got confused between placeholder and label. Cheers!